# Reduce size of iText generated PDF including time series bar chart

Tags: itext, jfreechart

Adding a time series bar chart for a large time span in PDF results in large file size like 50 MB or more depending on the data points. Here are the code samples:

#### Adding chart to PDF

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(RESULT));
document.open();
PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
float width = PageSize.A4.getWidth();
float height = PageSize.A4.getHeight() / 2;

PdfTemplate bar = cb.createTemplate(width, height);
Graphics2D g2d2 = new PdfGraphics2D(bar, width, height);
Rectangle2D r2d2 = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, width, height);
getBarChart().draw(g2d2, r2d2);
g2d2.dispose();
cb.addTemplate(bar, 0, 0);
document.close();
```

#### Creating chart

```
JFreeChart getBarChart() {
    TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("Data");
    
    GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    for (int i=0; i<365*24; i++) {
        cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
        series.addOrUpdate(new Millisecond(cal.getTime()), Math.random());
    }
    
    XYPlot plot = new XYPlot();
    plot.setDataset(new XYBarDataset(new TimeSeriesCollection(series), 10));
    plot.setRenderer(new XYBarRenderer());
    plot.setRangeAxis(new NumberAxis());
    plot.setDomainAxis(new DateAxis());

    return new JFreeChart(plot);
}
```

How can I reduce the file size?

Using itextpdf-5.4.4 and jfreechart-1.0.15.

Comment: Can you provide a sample PDF that it produces? That would help us determine where the bloat is coming from.

Comment: [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7dMARru2-5zRjNmc1p4a016Z00/edit?usp=sharing) is the output of the sample code.

Comment: Wow, there's a lot of data points in there! I would try turning off the drop shadows first. I would think that might cut the file size at least in half. http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/BarRenderer.html#setShadowVisible(boolean)

Comment: Looking deeper, do you actually need to have a vector version of the chart? If not, you might want to just render to a high DPI image and embed that. I don't know if it is JFree or `PdfGraphics2D` doing it but that chart is made up of tens of thousands of objects instead of just simple lines. My guess is that the gradients on the bars are also adding to the complexity, I'd try making those solid if possible, too.

Comment: You might also try setting a different default bar painter (`XYBarRenderer.setDefaultBarPainter()`). The initial value of that is the `GradientXYBarPainter`, and using gradients for so small bars makes the required drawing operations and operators explode while only making a difference at a gigantic zoom level, if at all.

Comment: Dropping shadows decreased the size, but it didn't help much. Using StandardXYBarPainter has solved my issue as @mkl suggested.

Comment: @chingeez Ok, as it solves your problem, I'll make it an answer in its own right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While inspecting the PDF provided by the OP, it quickly becomes apparent that it is full of **Pattern** definitions and the like used for drawing pretty bars. To reduce the PDF size, therefore, simplifying the bar design is the way to go.

In the case at hand this can be done by setting a different default bar painter (using `XYBarRenderer.setDefaultBarPainter()`). The initial value of that attribute is a `GradientXYBarPainter`, but using gradients for so small bars makes the number of required drawing operations and operators explode while only making a difference at a gigantic zoom level, if at all.

As already worked out in the comments to the question, using the `StandardXYBarPainter` instead solves the size issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set full compression and compare the difference:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new FileInputStream("in.pdf"));
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream("out.pdf"));
int total = reader.getNumberOfPages() + 1;
for ( int i=1; i<total; i++) {
    reader.setPageContent(i + 1, reader.getPageContent(i + 1));
}
stamper.setFullCompression();
stamper.close();
```

Comment: Setting full compression reduces the size from 170MB to 32MB, but it is still a large file. Changing bar chart to line chart reduces the size to 500KB.